# Generate Number Range in a List of Numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, list

I am using C# and have a list of int numbers which contains different numbers such as {34,36,40,35,37,38,39,4,5,3}. Now I need a script to find the different ranges in the list and write it on a file. for this example it would be: (34-40) and (3-5). What is the quick way to do it?

thanks for the help in advance;

Comment: Well obviously your first step should be to sort the numbers.  Then the problem becomes a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike said, first sort the list. Now, starting with the first element, remember that element, then compare it with the next one. If the next element is 1 greater than the current one, you have a contiguous series. Continue this until the next number is NOT contiguous. When you reach that point, you have a range from the first remembered value to the current value. Remember/output that range, then start again with the next value as the first element of a new series. This will execute in roughly 2N time (linear).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to sort the array and then do a single sequential pass to capture the ranges. That will most likely be fast enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Two techniques come to mind: histogramming and sorting. Histogramming will be good for dense number sets (where you have most of the numbers between min and max) and sorting will be good if you have sparse number sets (very few of the numbers between min and max are actually used).

For histogramming, simply walk the array and set a Boolean flag to True in the corresponding position histogram, then walk the histogram looking for runs of True (default should be false).

For sorting, simply sort the array using the best applicable sorting technique, then walk the sorted array looking for contiguous runs.

EDIT: some examples.

Let's say you have an array with the first 1,000,000 positive integers, but all even multiples of 191 are removed (you don't know this ahead of time). Histogramming will be a better approach here.

Let's say you have an array containing powers of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, ...) and 3 (3, 9, 27, 81, ...). For large lists, the list will be fairly sparse and sorting should be expected to do better.

Answer (score 0):

I would sort them and then check for consecutive numbers. If the difference > 1 you have a new range.